# Create seq of maps from two or more seqs

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap, seq

I'm new to Clojure and I was wondering if there's a way to create a sequence of maps from two or more sequences.

Let's say you have:

```
(def numbers '(1 2 3))
(def letters '("a" "b" "c"))
(def shapes '("circle" "square" "triangle"))
```

If you merged those I'd like to get what would be an array of hashes in Ruby, or in Clojure a sequence of maps?

```
({:number 1, :letter "a", :shape "circle"} {:number 2, :letter "b", :shape "square"} {:number 3, :letter "c", :shape "triangle"})
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 (map (fn [n l s] {:number n, :letter l, :shape s})  numbers letters shapes) ;;=> 
 ({:number 1, :letter "a", :shape "circle"} {:number 2, :letter "b", :shape "square"} {:number 3, :letter "c", :shape "triangle"})
```

Comment: Haha, we posted exactly the same answer at exactly the same time! I can't do anything but +1

Comment: Haha, I will +1 yours too, what a co-incidence! :)

Comment: lol, thanks guys, I flipped a coin and @MichielBorkent gets the answer

Comment: A more idiomatic way than coin-flipping: `(rand-nth '[dbaupp michiel-borkent])`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there is a more idiomatic way to do this, but:

```
(map (fn [n l s] {:number n, :letter l, :shape s}) numbers letters shapes)
```

Or even

```
(map #(do {:number %1, :letter %2, :shape %3}) numbers letters shapes)
```